# How to add data into a Div popup

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a button on my page that shows some informations about specific projects. I used to redirect the user to a page showing these informations, so i simply used `Action= site.com/main?var=<?=$Var?...`

However, i've been requested to show this information into a popup. So i coded in a Div popup, but i really don't know how to send the data onto it. Here is the code inside this Div:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['proj_id'])||!empty($_POST['task_uid']))
            die("Invalid proj_id or task_uid.");

        $query = "
        SELECT  pm.id,
                pm.proj_id,
                pm.task_uid,
                pp.task_id,
                pp.pipeline_name,
                pm.proj_pipeline_order,
                pcrs.gestor_projeto,
                pcrs.prioridade,
                pcrs.tecnologia,
                pcrs.resp_programa,
                eng.ativo

        FROM    projetos_main pm

        INNER JOIN projetos_pipeline pp
                  ON pm.task_uid = pp.task_uid

        RIGHT JOIN pcrs
                  ON pp.pcr = pcrs.num_doc

        LEFT JOIN engcom.top_issues_main eng
                  ON pcrs.num_doc = eng.pcr

                 WHERE pm.pcr = '".$_GET['pcr']."'

                 ORDER BY pm.task_uid ASC


            ";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


    ?>
        <tr>
    <td>
<label style='top: 5px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center'>
    PCR Information:
</label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <table style='margin:0 auto; margin-top: 45px;'>


    <tr>
        <td><b>Pipeline:</b></td>
        <td><?=$row['pipeline_name']?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><b>Project Position:</b></td>
        <td><?=$row['task_id']?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><b>Project Manager:</b></td>
        <td><?=$row ['gestor_projeto']?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
        <td><b>Portfolio Manager:</b></td>
        <td><?=$row['resp_programa']?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><b>Top Issue:</b></td>
        <td><?=$row ['ativo']?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
        <td><b>Technology:</b></td>
        <td><?=$row ['tecnologia']?></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

As you can see, i tried doing a Select inside of the Div. It didn't work in the end. Also, it might be important to note that this popup is located in a separate file from my main site. This Select over here is from About.php

I have a js that i use to show or hide the popup:

```
function exibirAbout(){
    document.getElementById('popupAbout').style.display = 'block';
}

function ocultarAbout(){
    document.getElementById('popupAbout').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Pretty basic code, really. And here is the button that calls that function. It used to be located inside a form which sent the data onto the new page, but now this form has no "Action" anymore. It looks like this:

```
<form method="post" target="popupAbout">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" onclick="exibirAbout();" value="About"/>
                                    </form>
```

I'm at a loss, honestly, i have no idea how to do it, and i can't find it around the site. Keep in mind that i'm at work and cannot use Jquery, as we don't use it here. Any ideas?

Would it be better to drop the Div and use an Iframe? Would that solve anything?

Comment: You should read about `AJAX` and `XHRequest` and use `JS` to implement this

Comment: The php side is really dangerous, you're directly injecting a GET variable inside your query without escaping the values. This may result in a very easy SQL injection, I would rather start caring about that first and, then, about the fact that mysql_* prototype is officially deprecated, hence you should either migrate to mysqli_* or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

PHP code is executed before HTML/Javascript, so it does not matter if you do the query "inside the div". In fact your program should be structured to do "inputs" first, then "processing" and in the end "output". When you mix output and processing you may run into problems (for example if you want to send a redirect-header).

Then, you could write all data into the (hidden) div when the site is generated and show it on a specific event. But it seems you'll need the information with the POST request... then your solution is AJAX (JS send a request to a PHP script without reloading the whole page). In this case, you can add the results dynamically.
Please note: AJAX is Javascript technique not specific to jquery. You might not want to use jquery, but you WILL have to use javascript. I'd recommend a JS library though, as it makes life easier.

Last site note: don't use "onclick" for the button, but "onsubmit" for the form - a form can be submitted without clicking the submit button!